# Unable to connect to all storage backends successfully with PredictionIO and Elasticsearch on Localhost

Tags: elasticsearch, predictionio

I'm trying to setup PredictionIO locally following [these](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/install/) instructions.

Unfortunately I'm unable to get it to work. When I try to install a template or run "pio status" I get the error saying that PredictionIO is unable to connect to elasticsearch:

```
[ERROR] [Console$] Unable to connect to all storage backends successfully. The following shows the error message from the storage backend.
[ERROR] [Console$] None of the configured nodes are available: [] (org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException)
[ERROR] [Console$] Dumping configuration of initialized storage backend sources. Please make sure they are correct.
[ERROR] [Console$] Source Name: ELASTICSEARCH; Type: elasticsearch; Configuration: HOME -> /Users/tomasz/Documents/PredictionIO/apache-predictionio-0.10.0-incubating/PredictionIO-0.10.0-incubating/vendors/elasticsearch-1.4.4, HOSTS -> localhost, PORTS -> 9200, TYPE -> elasticsearch
```

My pio-env.sh file is setup like so:

```
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=HBASE

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=LOCALFS

PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_PORTS=9200
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/elasticsearch-1.4.4

PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_LOCALFS_TYPE=localfs
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_LOCALFS_PATH=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/models

PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_TYPE=hbase
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/hbase-1.0.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when I was using Elasticsearch 5.4.x on PredictionIO version 0.11.0-incubating. It worked when I used Elasticsearch 1.7.x